# Change Info Shown in VS 2010 DataTip

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I am attempting to find a way to alter the information that is shown in a DataTip in the VS 2010 Debugger.  The purpose being that I would like to choose what property value is shown on the initial window of a DataTip.

For example, when hovering over a collection in debug mode I am presented with the Name of the collection followed by its Count property's value.

This is useful information, but when I am hovering over one of my custom objects I am only presented with a path providing the type of object it is (in my case something like BOS.SuggestedOrdersDataEntity.SuggestedOrdersEntity).

I would like to have this initial DataTip window contain the property that I would determine to be the most useful depending on what custom object it is. For instance it could be the case that for an object that is of type SuggestedOrdersEntity it would be more helpful for the DataTip to show the value of its VendorName property in place of BOS.SuggestedOrdersDataEntity.SuggestedOrdersEntity (similar to the way collections show their Count property).  The goal is to not have to use the '+' expander to find the current value of the VendorName (or whatever property is most useful).

I would like to be able to alter the DataTips so that I can customize them to immediately show a specific property's value (just like Count shows for collections) without needing to expand and view all the properties.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I've done some researching on DataTips, but nothing I have found discusses customizing them in this way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**`DebuggerDisplay`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx) attribute, examples [here](http://chrisfulstow.com/customising-visual-studio-debugger-datatips-with-debuggerdisplay).

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{Name} - {StockSymbol}")]
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StockSymbol { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public Company(string name) { Name = name; }
}
```